# can't access file resources in a servlet using Netbeans 7.1.2

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

I have Netbeans 7.1.2 running and I am trying to access some text files within a servlet:

```
package com.optimizations.cutting;

@WebServlet(name = "Servlet", urlPatterns = {"/Servlet"})
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("in servlet "+System.currentTimeMillis());

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {

        DataManager dm = new DataManager();
        SheetInfo si = dm.loadSheetInfoCSV("sheetInfo.csv");
        ArrayList<Piece> pieces = dm.loadPiecesCSV("res/pieces4.csv");
....
```

I have placed the `sheetInfo.csv` and the `pieces4.csv` files everywhere i could think of, trying to acces them with a backslash ahead ( `/sheetInfo.csv` or `/res/pieces4.csv` )

when i say "everywhere i could think of" i mean : current directory (source packages), next to `Servlet.java` and all the other files I created (including `DataManager.java` which uses it). I also did the `"Add folder"` in the `Properties window`->`Sources`->`Package Folder`. (added 2 folders, just to make sure ). So my dear files are in 3 places all at once:

- `src/java/com/optimizations/cutting`   next to `Servlet.java` and `DataManager.java`
- `src/java/res`
- `src/resources`
  but i stll get the

  ```
  SEVERE: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources/pieces4.csv (No such file or directory)

  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)

  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)

  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)

  at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)

  at com.optimizations.cutting.DataManager.loadPiecesCSV(DataManager.java:98)`
  ```

I have also restarted the server (Glassfish 3.1.2)

(maybe this seems silly but I also need to know where and how should i place my files so they can be accessed from both the client and the server - my servlet will create some images(.jpg) and store them (where?) and will send the filenames back to a .jsp which will then show them in a colorbox)

thanks in advance.

**edit**

added some more lines of the error and
the call in DataManager.java:

```
public SheetInfo loadSheetInfoCSV(String filename){
    ....
    br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(filename));
    String strLine = "";            

    //read comma separated file first line
    if ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception suggests that you were using `FileInputStream` to get an `InputStream` of it. This is not the right way when the resource concerns a classpath resource (all places where you attempted to put it in are part of the classpath). You should get a classpath resource as a classpath resource using `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`, not as a local disk file system resource using `FileInputStream`.

If the resource file `foo.ext` is placed in the same package as the class where you're trying to load the resource (i.e. the `DataManager` class), then you can just use get an `InputStream` of it by its sole filename as follows:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo.ext");
```

Or when you're inside the `static` context:

```
InputStream input = DataManager.class.getResourceAsStream("foo.ext");
```

If the resource `foo.ext` is placed in a different package than the class where you're trying to load the resource, e.g. the `com.example` package, then you can get an `InputStream` of it by its classpath-relative path as follows, where the leading slash `/` takes you to the root of the classpath:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/example/foo.ext");
```

Also here, the `getClass()` can be substituted by an arbitraty `Foo.class`, as long as the class is loaded by the same `ClassLoader` which has access to the same package structure.

An alternative is to use the context `ClassLoader` as obtained from the current thread. It has access to *everything*. You only can't specify a classpath-relative path, it is always relative to the root of the classpath (so no leading slash `/` should be used):

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/example/foo.ext");
```

Comment: ok..so i will edit to show the exact method i used to get the files (i did not directly use FileInputStream. Anyway... my wonder is why this method worked for a simple Java project (not web, but desktop). what i mean is that i tested the DataManager class in a simple desktop java project then just added it to my source package in the web proj.

Comment: i will try what you suggested and my bet is that it will work :) . I still wish to understand the reason why that first one didn't, but the important thing is to get it working.

Comment: okay the reading part worked just fine :). i need to get to the writing part (which of course fails right now (it uses  File file = new File(filename);
            try {
                ImageIO.write(sheet, "png", file);

Comment: (continuing.. since i am not alowed to edit comments after 5 min have passed).But I guess it's fixable in the same manner. ...Still why is it working on a desktop app (and not a web) ? and how do I write them to be seen by the client browser? (I'll start some googling anyway)

Comment: You didn't mention that you need to be able to write to it. That drastically changes the answer. You should not put it in the classpath, but on a fixed location in the local disk file system. You can then use the `FileInputStream`/`FileOutputStream` the usual way (but with an absolute path!!). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream/2308388#2308388 To serve it to the world wide web, just add the location as virtual host to the server config, or create a servlet which streams it.

Comment: thanks for the answer (btw.. i did mention i also need writing to some files, and that I am using a servlet for that: check the paragraph before "thanks in advance"  :) ).